# Tag Synonym Request [sound-problem] -> [sound]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I dont really think we need both [sound](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/sound) and [sound-problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/sound-problem) tags.

Doesn't both of them mean the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it was made a synonym, but not merged. I've merged them.

[image]